# link_to another page in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I just want to create a link to the page `app/views/layouts/world.html.erb`. How can I do this? (Using link_to or something similar) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a layout, which means you embed pages in it, even if it wasn't rails doesn't have a concept of linking to "pages", you link to "resources".

I understand that is a confusing answer, and would recommend going through something like this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book